# Modify Image Left Publishing page layout to add related items column on right side

Tags: page-layout

I am creating a news item layout that displays the article in view and uses the CQWP to display filtered related items to the article in view using metadata via a News Category Term Store term. I need to modify a copy of the Image Left OOB layout to add a column for the CQWP to as a sidebar to the page. Have all the parts working together but can't figure out how to add the sidebar. The article info items render 100% wide and push the CQWP under the article vs to the right side.